# python go to next iteration if a iteration got erro

Tags: python, loops, try-catch

I am new to python. I have tried to write a code for downloading PDFs from a site. I am getting HTTP.error after downloading of around 3000 files. The program should skip downlaoding of file in case.

```
import requests,bs4,os,time,wget,sys
url = str(input("type the url:"))# type URL

res=requests.get(url) # get url in requests module
res.raise_for_status() # test whether the link 
print("request raised")
pdf_links = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text,"html5lib") # read the webpage using HTML
print ("read website")

empty_list = []

i = 0
for link in pdf_links.findAll(title="PDF file that opens in a new window"):
    i+=1
print(i)
get_url = link.get('href') # get all link addresses
com_url = str("http://ciconline.nic.in//rti/docs/"+str(get_url)) #combine link address with URL of website
empty_list.append(com_url)
print ("appended list")

for j in range(len(empty_list)):
   while True:
      try:
        list_link = empty_list[j]
        print ("downloading %d.%s"%(j,list_link))
        wget.download(list_link,"D:\RTI\CIC-JAN-MAR-2016")

    except:
        print("Oops!",sys.exc_info()[0],"occured.")
        print("started iteration %d"%j)
        continue
    break
```

Answer (score 1):

You should probably avoid a while loop here; the following will skip over the entry, and attempt to download the next one, in case of an error

```
for j in range(len(empty_list)):
    try:
        list_link = empty_list[j]
        print ("downloading %d.%s"%(j,list_link))
        wget.download(list_link,"D:\RTI\CIC-JAN-MAR-2016")

    except:
        print("Oops!",sys.exc_info()[0],"occured.")
        print("started iteration %d"%j)
        continue
```

Comment: Yep, agreed :) Was just about to make the same answer.